# asset.rb in config/initializers - Rails App 3.2.13, Ruby 2.0.0-p0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer, assets

In one of the Rails app I am working, I could find a file called

```
asset.rb
```

inside `config/initializers` directory and it contains the following details:

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
  if request.env["REQUEST_PATH"].include? ".pdf"
    "file://#{Rails.root.join('public')}"
  else
    "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
  end
}
```

Can anyone tell me what it really means. We have PDF report generation functionality in our app. Anyway, I have searched a lot and couldn't find a better answer.

Please help. Thanks :)-

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your pdf files (probably generated by your PDF report generation) are stored in `/public` directory.  What that code is doing is first checking if the path of the request contains the string ".pdf".

If `REQUEST_PATH` contains `.pdf` then sets `Base.asset_host` to `file://path_to_app/public` otherwise e.g. `https://host:port`.

So I think what is being done somewhere is, if there is a request for `pdf` file then serve the file over `file://` protocol regardless of the request protocol, and for any other files use the request protocol.

You could search within your application for `Base.asset_host` to see where and how this is being used.